# Application events sync with iCloud account

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, icloud

We are developing calendar syncing application in iOS. User can create event in application, we are keeping event in iCal and coredata in iCloud (storing event eventIdentifier in core data to identify event of our application).

I have one issue related to event eventIdentifier

for eg: if user create an event with one iCloud account and switch to another account, after some time if user switch back to first account ical calendar will sync and shows previously created event in iCal but not in my application.

My application need to check with iCal events identifier with icloud db event id, but its not matching while synchronising

Is there any other event unique identifier that fulfil my requirement?